# ODT and Visual Studio -- total fail

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015, dataprovider

I'm not an Oracle guy and need to use it from Visual Studio.  I installed Oracle Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 but can't get by some odd error messages.  The first time I start VS and try to add a new connection (any connection), I get the message:

> Oracle Data Provider for .NET has been installed without a
>   machine-wide configuration. However, a version of Oracle Data Provider
>   for .NET has been detected in the Global Assembly Cache which may be
>   incompatible.  Please remove Oracle Data Provider for .NET from the
>   Global Assembly Cache and restart Visual Studio.

This is odd, because I just did exactly what the message said.  The next time I started VS, the error popped up again.

If I OK that message, I get another one:

> Failed to find the default tnsnames.ora.  Could not load type
>   OracleInternal.Common.ConfigBaseClass' from assembly
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=Neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342

I'm not at all sure what that means.

Any ideas out there?

UPDATES:

Didn't create tnsnames.ora (don't know how to).  Did I miss a step in installation? (Don't remember that being mentioned).  In the machine config I have:

```
<section name="oracle.dataaccess.client" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

Oracle is not found in the user.config file.  the dll info:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>gacutil /l Oracle.ManagedDat
aAccess
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8
9b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

No .NET config file at this point. in VS I'm just trying to connect with server Explorer

Comment: Findings back in main post

Comment: This does not match. You copy/paste `oracle.dataaccess` but query GAC for "Oracle. **Managed**DataAccess"

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing that out. I'm not sure what that means. I naively expected odt to work out of the box. Now I don't know what I need to do. I want it to work without becoming an Oracle DBA.

Comment: Did you check value for `/configuration/oracle.manageddataaccess.client/version/settings/setting/@name=TNS_ADMIN` in your .NET config file? Does it show the folder where your `tnsnames.ora` file is stored. In order to create a `tnsnames.ora` file, ask your DBA.

Comment: Yes, it does, and tnsnames.ora is there.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create any `tnsnames.ora` file? If yes, where did you save it. Unlike other clients, ODP.NET Managed Driver does not use `TNS_ADMIN` variable from environment settings or Registry.

Check content of `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` element in your .NET config files `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`, resp.  of `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` element in your .NET config files `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config` and/or local config files (`user.config` and `web.config`)

See [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm) for more information.

Compare configuration in .NET config file , e.g.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

with actually installed DLL, e.g.:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>gacutil /l Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.18020
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL

Number of items = 2

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>
```

Answer (score -1):

The TNS names error is due to a missing TNSNames.ora file, usually found in the C:\app\userprofile\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin for Oracle 11g.  The TNSnames.ora file contains the database connection information.  You didn't say what version of the Oracle Client you installed, so the version number may be different.  I always install a full client and during that process the TNS configuration program runs and installs and configures the TNSNames.org file.  I'm not familiar with Oracle Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015, but there must be some sort of configuration tool to connect you with the database.

To install the full client, you can download the install from Oracle.com at this link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

Installing the full client will also resolve the GAC problem as well.  Apparently the version installed is not compatible with your database installation.

Comment: According error message the ODP.NET **Managed Driver** is used. This one does not use any Oracle client, it runs stand-alone.

Comment: Yes, I see that.  I'm suggesting that they use the full client.

Comment: But then you should also state to use the (unmanaged) ODP.NET provider is Visual Studio.

Comment: Regardless of the client type, the overriding issue is the lack of TNSNames.ora which provides the connection information for a  connection to the database.  Without that, no connection is possible from any client.  Whatever client the user ultimately decides to use, the TNSNames.ora is required.

Comment: There are several other possibilities, for example Easy Connect or Oracle Name server (Directory naming). All these do not require any `tnsnames.ora` file, see [Understanding Naming Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/concepts.htm#NETAG186). Or you can put entire connect descriptor manually in connect string.

Comment: Which is NOT the issue here.

Comment: I don't have this directory: C:\app\userprofile\product

Comment: You probably do not given that you do not have a full client installed.  You are using the Oracle Managed Data Access client which is configured differently than the full client.  See @Wernfried Domscheit answer, I'm not familiar with the  Oracle Managed Data Access client as all I've ever used is the full client.

Comment: Precisely. I just got the tools for Visual Studio downloaded and installed. It didn't mention any pre/coreqs so I didn't install any